# why my static variable is not available in main method?

Tags: java, methods, static, block, program-entry-point

I dont know if I forgot my basics even after couple of years working on java.

I have a class which has a static block

```
static {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    try {
        prop.load(new FileInputStream("PATH OF PROPERTIES FILE"));
        String properties22 = (String) prop.getProperty("propertyname");
        properties22Tokens = new StringTokenizer(properties22, ",");

         while(properties22Tokens.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            System.out.print(":::"+properties22Tokens.nextToken());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have declared public static declaration on that variable like below

public static StringTokenizer properties22Tokens;

and I am trying to print the tokens in main method like below .. but there are no tokens..
which is eating the tokens ?

```
public static void main(String arg[]) {

    System.out.print("in main..");

    while(properties22Tokens.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        System.out.print(":::"+properties22Tokens.nextToken());
    }

}
```

Output is - some tokens from the propeties + in main..

My expected output - some tokens from the properties + in main.. + some tokens from the properties

Could someone please fix and explain the fix ?

Answer (score 2):

yes, Tom is right. You "ate" them all in the static block.
Following piece of code return false.
**while(properties22Tokens.hasMoreTokens()){

  .......

}**

Now question is why?
Because when we will create object of StringTokenizer and populate it. It will create two variables. One for total size of your StringTokenizer object's tokens. And second for check how many tokens have been served to you.
At the time of invoking hasMoreTokens() over stringTokenizer, It will compare both variable value and return boolean value it may be true or false.
And when invoking nextToken() over stringTokenizer, It will increase value of variable, which is created for knowing how many tokens have been served.

Answer (score 0):

You "ate" them all in the static block. By the time `main` happens, `while(properties22Tokens.hasMoreTokens())` will be false.

Comment: Yes, it is false.. but why ?

Comment: thank you Tom ... but if I want to iterate couple of times on same variable in the same class from different methods what would be the best practice  ?

Comment: You need to create a fresh `StringTokenizer` from the property value each time.

Answer (score 0):

StringTokenizer class break the string in tokens and tokens can be iterated using `nextToken` method. As you have traversed all the tokens in static block using the following loop:

```
while(properties22Tokens.hasMoreTokens())
{
    System.out.print(":::"+properties22Tokens.nextToken());
}
```

so any further calls of `hasMoreTokens` will return `false`. Hence your `while` loop in `main` method never executes.

Comment: Thanks for explanation .. I fixed and assigning my tokens to an array variable to reuse wherever I required..